# Can I play Deltarune without a Windows or Mac PC?

Tags: deltarune

I played Undertale on my Switch and I'd like to get Deltarune. Is there any way I can play Deltarune without a Windows or Mac PC?

Comment: Are you fine with modding? You can replace the data.<something> file with LayeredFS of Undertale to play deltarune instead.

Answer (score 2):

As of September 23 2021, Deltarune: Chapter 1 & 2 are available on [Nintendo Switch](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/deltarune-chapter-1-switch/), [PlayStation 4](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP3893-CUSA15235_00-TFSHVCDRPS400084/), and [PC/MacOS](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1671210/DELTARUNE/). The Steam version can be played on Linux via Proton.

Answer (score 1):

What platform will you play on?

**As a GNU/Linux shill, I will describe the steps to get Deltarune running.**

First, install [WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org/) (allows Windows executables to run on Linux). Then, download the **MicrosoftⓇ Windows™** copy from the game vendor's official website.

Alternatively, you could just use a good 'ol VM or just dualboot (like I do).

Comment: Well, I think I will try it on Linux...I'm just starting to play around with it here and there.  I'm new, so I cannot vote on this answer, but this is the number one(only)answer!  Congratulations!!!

Comment: Btw, there is an in-depth unofficial guide (or plain ol' downloads if you prefer) for running Deltarune on Linux natively (without Wine): https://www.reddit.com/r/Deltarune/comments/9wizh3/deltarune_running_on_linux_natively/

Comment: I don't think so!